# Life Counter in Greenfoot caught "Incompatible Types" exception

Tags: java, exceptions

I need to make a life counter so that when my Actor get hit by an Enemy, his life will be decreased by 1.

I put this method in my `Actor` class:

```
private void decreaseLife() {
    Actor enemy = getOneIntersectingObject(Enemy.class);
    if (enemy != null) {
        int lastIndex = Scenario.getLifeBar().size()-1;
        Life LastLife = Scenario.getLifeBar().get(lastIndex);
        /** catch error on lastIndex --> "incompatible types" **/

        getWorld().removeObject(enemy);

        getWorld().removeObject(LastLife);
        Scenario.getLifeBar().remove(lastIndex);
    }
}
```

I used `Scenario.getLifeBar().size() - 1;` to get the last index from my `ArrayList` collection then decrease it by 1. My `LifeMax` was set to 3, so when decreased by 1 it should be returning value = 2, and be saved in `lastIndex`.

This is my code including `LifeBar` code in `Scenario` Class:

```
import greenfoot.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scenario extends World {   
    private final int LIFE_MAX = 3; //Max value of my Actor's life
    private static ArrayList LifeBar = new ArrayList();

    public Scenario() {   
        super(600, 400, 1); 
        prepare();}

    private void prepare() {     
        prepareLifeBar(40, 30);
        // Add obj. main actor
        // Add obj.enemy
    }

    private void prepareLifeBar(int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        int spaceBetweenLife = 10;  // just to put space between image
        for (int i = 0; i < LIFE_MAX; i++) {
            Life life = new Life();
            life.setLocationX(offsetX+((life.getImage().getWidth()+spaceBetweenLife)*i) );
            nyawa.setLocatinY(offsetY);
            addObject(life, life.getLocationX(), life.getLocationY());
            LifeBar.add(life);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList getLifeBar() {
        return LifeBar;
    }
}
```

In my `Life` class, I put some code to add attributes of `LocationX` and `LocationY` to save my `Life` actor in x and y axis.

I believe there's no other exception caught in any other class related to my life counter, yet my `lastIndex` caught an incompatible types exception.

**What's causing this exception to be thrown?**

Comment: Hey, welcome to GameDev.SE! I edited your question, but I decided to not add a `Greenfoot` tag as I don't think that framework is relevant to your issue (I'm happy to be proved wrong though!).

Comment: @Alex Yes, thanks for editing..! It looks more to the point right now. Actually I was looking for greenfoot-related questions in GameDev before, but found out that it's not yet become tag.. that's why I was suggesting :D

Comment: I see, it's possible that there simply are no questions specifically relating to Greenfoot. If you do have any of your own though, please go ahead and ask them! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my arraylist elements stored as Object objects (not as Life objects). So I need to cast the element as type Life first,

I need to change this :

```
Life LastLife = Scenario.getLifeBar().get(lastIndex);
```

into this :

```
Life LastLife =  (Life) SpaceWorld.getLifeBar().get(lastIndex);
```

and it works just fine.

Check the [Reference](http://www.greenfoot.org/topics/53894/0) here